# docker pull hello-world - msg="filesystem layer verification failed for digest"

Tags: docker

Docker: 1.9.1

OS: Oracle Linux Server 6.7

When I try to pull any image I've got following error:

```
975b84d108f1: Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io/library/hello-world, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer (3f12c794407e68e515ba7f473a744e748ac8a827a2ea8b33855dec564238b2e5) 473a744e748ac8a827a2ea8b33855dec564238b2e5)
Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io/library/hello-world, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer (3f12c794407e68e515ba7f473a744e748ac8a827a2ea8b33855dec564238b2e5)
```

I run command:

```
    sudo docker pull hello-world
```

result is:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
b901d36b6f2f: Verifying Checksum
0a6ba66e537a: Verifying Checksum
Pulling repository docker.io/library/hello-world
975b84d108f1: Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io/library/hello-world, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer (3f12c794407e68e515ba7f473a744e748ac8a827a2ea8b33855dec564238b2e5) 473a744e748ac8a827a2ea8b33855dec564238b2e5)
Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io/library/hello-world, Server error: Status 0 while fetching image layer (3f12c794407e68e515ba7f473a744e748ac8a827a2ea8b33855dec564238b2e5)</i>
```

I've checked /var/log/docker

```
time="2016-02-19T08:07:58.643914886-05:00" level=info msg="POST /v1.21/images/create?fromImage=hello-world%3Alatest"
time="2016-02-19T08:08:29.616886031-05:00" level=error msg="filesystem layer verification failed for digest sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84406680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4"
time="2016-02-19T08:08:29.617006230-05:00" level=error msg="filesystem layer verification failed for digest sha256:03f4658f8b782e12230c1783426bd3bacce651ce582a4ffb6fbbfa2079428ecb"
```

Same error occurs, if I try to pull any other image.